# Compare Time for two different columns and create third column which shows the difference in time

Tags: sql-server, datediff

Hi i have two columns with n number of rows of time in 24 hour format.

I want to compare the time for each row, which means entire `Column1` compared with `Column2` = `result_Column3`(time diff for both the columns)

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15  and try yourself

Comment: Hi, i went through it only issue is i don't understand how to apply datediff to entire columns.

Comment: `datediff(minute,column1,column2)` ?

Comment: This is helpful, also is it possible to create a query where we receive a difference in the format of Hh:mm, where in minutes are more than 60 than it becomes 1 hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your result_Column3 as,

```
UPDATE tblData SET result_Column3 = CONCAT((DATEDIFF(Minute,Column1,Column2)/60),':',(DATEDIFF(Minute,Column1,Column2)%60))
```